# Configure one virtual host handling specific subdomain (or directory) and another virtual host catching all others

Tags: apache2, subdomain, virtualhost

I want to configure a VirtualHost for subdomain.mydomain.tld with own DocumentRoot.
and another VitualHost with own DocumentRoot catching all others.

I tried

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias subdomain.mydomain.tld
...
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld mydomain.tld
...
</VirtualHost >
```

and it diddn't work properly...

any other suggestions?
If there is no way to fix this, i would like to map a virtulahost to a subfolder of mydomain.tld and let the other VirtualHost handle the rest, but no clue how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) apache can get a bit confused about which vhost should be used to serve a request.

Try poping in ServerName in as below

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain.mydomain.tld
...
</VirtualHost >

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mydomain.tld 
   ServerAlias *.mydomain.tld 
...
</VirtualHost >
```

Comment: Actually i have ServerName specified like you did. Did you left out the serveralias for the subdomain for reason?

Comment: Yeah, servername and serveralias both help apache identify the vhost. If it only has one name there is no need for an alias.

Comment: thanks.. seemed to work. I might have another problem with an old cached R=301 redirect. This solution worked at least for another browser ;)